# PHP- in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two `arrays`- one `single` and other `multi-dimensional`.

```
$abc='["first","second","third","fourth"]';

$def='[{"post_id":"1","postid":"42","tags":["eminem","baby","jordan"]},{"post_id":"3","postid":"38","tags"
:["abc","def","jordan"]},{"post_id":"4","postid":"40","tags":["eminem","baby","first","second","fourth"
]}]';

$ghi=json_decode($def,true);
$jkl=json_decode($abc,true);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($jkl);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ghi);

echo '</pre>';
```

And this is what it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
    [2] => third
    [3] => fourth
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [postid] => 42
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => eminem
                    [1] => baby
                    [2] => jordan
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 3
            [postid] => 38
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abc
                    [1] => def
                    [2] => jordan
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 4
            [postid] => 40
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => eminem
                    [1] => baby
                    [2] => first
                    [3] => second
                    [4] => fourth
                )

        )

)
```

What I am trying to do is search for the elements of single-dimensional array inside the sub-array `tags` present in the multi-dimensional array.

This is my code:

```
$users = array_unique($jkl);
$array = [];
$i=0;   

foreach($users as $user) 
{

    if (in_array($user, $ghi[$i]['tags'])) 
    {
        $newdata =  array (
            'postId' => $ghi[$i]['postid'],
            'tag' => $user
         );
        array_push($array, $newdata);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But I get the error mentioned as the question title. 
What could be the possible reason? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have the same amount of elements in both arrays, so you are trying to access elements in `$ghi` which don't even exist.

Comment: `$ghi[$i]['tags'])` --> `$i`  is undefined, so `$ghi[$i]` doesn't exists and  `$ghi[$i]['tags']` is not an array

Comment: Then how can I do such a comparison? @Marcos Pérez Gude

Comment: @SajeevC you can make a condition like `if(!empty($ghi[$i]) && !empty($ghi[$i]['tags']))` before `in_array()` condition

Comment: I want each single dimensional array element to be compared to each tag element of multi dimensional array and if there is a match, I need that corresponding postid. That's what I'm trying to acheive, @Anant

Comment: PHP arrays are really maps so assuming incremental keys is wrong more often than not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have to iterate through `multi-dimensional` array and do what you want:-*

```
<?php

$abc='["first","second","third","fourth"]';

$def='[{"post_id":"1","postid":"42","tags":["eminem","baby","jordan"]},{"post_id":"3","postid":"38","tags"
:["abc","def","jordan"]},{"post_id":"4","postid":"40","tags":["eminem","baby","first","second","fourth"
]}]';

$ghi=json_decode($def,true);
$jkl=json_decode($abc,true);

$users = array_unique($jkl);
$array = []; // empty array
foreach($ghi as $gh)  // iterate through multi-dimensional array not single one
{
for($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++){ // a for loop to iterate through single-dimensional completly
    if (in_array($users[$i],$gh['tags']))  // if single dimensional array value exist in multi-dimensional tags array
    {
        $newdata =  array (
            'postId' => $gh['postid'],
            'tag' => $users[$i]
         );
        array_push($array, $newdata); // push the data
    }
   }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($array); // print newly created array
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/602523

*Note:- Try to put variable name in such a way that they don't produce ambiguity.Thanks*

Comment: Yeah....this is just a sample but in original code, element names are not dummies like this. Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your both array has different numbers of elements. first array has four elements while second array has three elements. that's why you are getting problem.

You should check variable is set and must be an array. Use [!empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
foreach($users as $k=>$user){
  if(!empty($ghi[$k]['tags']) && is_array($ghi[$k]['tags'])) { // check this condition here
    if (in_array($user, $ghi[$k]['tags'])){
        $newdata =  array (
            'postId' => $ghi[$k]['postid'],
            'tag' => $user
         );
        array_push($array, $newdata);
    }
  }  
}
```

**Note**:- I have used array key as `$k` instead of `$i`

Answer (score 0):

This is because length of your 2 arrays are different, use `isset()` to remove error:

as 3rd index of your `$ghi` array does not exist, and its trying to fetch `$ghi[3]['tags']` - that's why error is occurring

Try:

```
foreach($users as $user) 
{
    if(isset($ghi[$i]['tags'])) { // just add this condition here
      if (in_array($user, $ghi[$i]['tags'])) 
      {
          $newdata =  array (
              'postId' => $ghi[$i]['postid'],
              'tag' => $user
           );
          array_push($array, $newdata);
      }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. I get empty array. @Jayesh Chitroda

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are searching for.
If you want to examine ALL of the $users against ALL of the $ghi array then you need to loop over both each time.

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($ghi); $i++) {
    if (in_array($user, $ghi[$i]['tags']))
    {
        $newdata =  array (
            'postId' => $ghi[$i]['postid'],
            'tag' => $user
         );
        array_push($array, $newdata);
    }
  }
}
```

This will result in the $newdata consisting of the following

```
array(2) { ["postId"]=> string(2) "40" ["tag"]=> string(6) "fourth" }
```

But if you only want to examine the each array against the other once. Then you need to check to make sure you're not going out of bounds.

$ghi only has 3 elements in it.
there are 4 elements in $users.

So you can either loop through the smaller array in your foreach - switch $users -> $ghi
or check inside the foreach loop that $ghi has a valid element at whatever $i is.

D.